# Prepared-statement not working while SQL query gets results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've come up with this problem and I don't have a clue about the reason it isn't working properly.

Basically I have this query where I join two different tables looking for precise information, pretty long but I think here is not the problem (but I will post it just in case):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT p.idplan, p.idautor,p.nombre,p.descripcion,p.privacidad,p.modified,a.nombre AS autor,
    IF(p.idautor IN (SELECT idamigo FROM pintiplan_amigos as am WHERE p.idautor=idamigo and am.idautor= ? ), 2, 
      IF (p.idautor = ? ,1, 3)) AS flagRelacion
  FROM pintiplan_planes AS p 
  LEFT JOIN pintiplan_autores AS a
    ON p.idautor=a.idautor
  HAVING ((p.privacidad=0) OR (p.idautor=?))  
    AND p.idplan IN (SELECT idplan FROM pintiplan_planes_sitios GROUP BY idplan HAVING count(1) > 1)
    AND (
      UPPER(p.nombre) LIKE UPPER (CONCAT('%',?,'%')) OR 
      UPPER(p.descripcion) LIKE UPPER (CONCAT('%',?,'%')))
) as plan
JOIN (
  SELECT s.idsitio,s.latitud,s.longitud,s.imagen,ps.idplan,ps.idautor,
  MIN(ACOS (
    SIN(RADIANS(?)) * 
    SIN(RADIANS(s.latitud))+ 
    COS(RADIANS(?)) * 
    COS(RADIANS(s.latitud))* 
    COS(RADIANS(?-s.longitud)))*6378.137) AS distancia
  FROM pintiplan_planes_sitios AS ps 
  RIGHT JOIN pintiplan_sitios AS s 
    ON (ps.idautor=s.idautor) AND (ps.idsitio=s.idsitio) 
  GROUP BY ps.idplan,ps.idautor
) as sitio 
ON sitio.idplan=plan.idplan AND sitio.idautor=plan.idautor 
HAVING sitio.distancia < ?
LIMIT ?,?
```

My issue here I think is with my php:

```
if (checkPostParameters(array("cadena","radio","idautor","lat","lon","pag"))){
  $cadena = $_POST["cadena"];
  $radio = $_POST["radio"];
  $idautor = $_POST["idautor"];
  $lat = $_POST["lat"];
  $lon = $_POST["lon"];
  $pag = $_POST["pag"];
} else reportError("Parametros POST no correctos o estan incompletos. Linea: ".__LINE__,$db);

$db = new Db();
$response = array();
$longPag = 50;
$curPag = $longPag * intval($pag);

$db->connect()->autocommit(FALSE);

$stmt = $db->connect()->prepare(
  "/* QUERY HERE */") 
  or reportError("El statement ha fallado. Error en la BD. Linea: ".__LINE__,$db);

$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssii",$idautor,$idautor,$idautor,$cadena,$cadena,$latitud,$latitud,$longitud,$distancia,$curPag, $longPag) 
or reportError("Fallo bindeando los parametros. Linea: ".__LINE__,$db);

$stmt->execute() 
or reportError("No se ha podido ejecutar la consulta. Fallo del servidor. Linea: ".__LINE__,$db);

$stmt->bind_result($idplan,$idautor,$nombre,$descripcion,$privacidad,$modified,$autor,$flagRelacion,$idsitio,$latitud,$longitud,$imagen,$idplan,$idautor,$distancia) 
or reportError("No se han podido asignar valores Linea: ".__LINE__,$db);
$response["planes"]=array();
while($stmt->fetch()){
  $plan=
    array(
      "idplan"=>$idplan,
      "idautor"=>$idautor,
      "nombre"=>$nombre,
      "descripcion"=>$descripcion,
      "privacidad"=>$privacidad,
      "fecha"=>$modified,
      "autor"=>$autor,
      "flagRelacion"=>$flagRelacion,
      "idsitio"=>$idsitio,
      "latitud"=>$latitud,
      "longitud"=>$longitud,
      "imagen"=>$imagen,
      "distancia"=>$distancia
    );
  $response["planes"][]=$plan;
}
$db->connect()->commit() 
or reportError("Fallo en la consignación de la transacción. Linea: ".__LINE__,$db);
$stmt->close();
```

I don't know why but the query works perfectly when I launch it directly in my DB but when I try to do it using php the `prepare()` function seems to stop working.

I have tried this:

```
$stmt->store_result();
var_dump($stmt->num_rows);
```

But the result is NULL. The program isn't crashing (die is not called)

```
function reportError ($message,$db){
  $response = array();
  $response["success"]=0;
  $response["message"]=$message;
  return die(print_r(json_encode($response),true));
} 

function checkPostParameters ($requiredParameters){
  $checked = true;
  foreach ($requiredParameters as $parameter){
    if(!array_key_exists($parameter, $_POST) OR is_null($_POST[$parameter])) {
      echo $parameter;
      $checked = false;
    } 
  }
  return $checked;
}
```

But the results are empty when they shouldn't be according to the query results. Do you have any idea of what is going on?

Comment: So what is the error is produces

Comment: @RiggsFolly is not and error actually, the script finishes but the array that should store the data remains empty when according to the query it should have been filled with many rows. When I tried to debug it I finded out that the prepare function is getting no data from the DB

Comment: Show what `reportError()` does. Do you output the actual mysqli error i.e. `$db->error`

Comment: Check your query log to find out what actual SQL sent to MySQL. Maybe the SQL actually does not return any result set as you expect

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added the function to the post, it's basically a custom `die()`

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara I didn't know I have a default MySQL log, could you tell me the path? (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Try Binding your LIMIT parameters as type `ii` instead of `ss`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Still not working but good point :)

Comment: In fact I would check the datatypes of all of your parameters

Comment: @RiggsFolly The rest of the parameters are comming by POST, they are passed as strings in order to use them in a query so I don't think that's the problem (I will add the part where I get the parameters)

Comment: You could try turning on the MYSQL General Log, then you shoudl be able to see the statement being prepared and then executed and thet might highlight where your error is

Comment: @Asur As RiggsFolly said, general query log does not turn on by default so you need to turn it on first, define where you want to store log and restart MySQL server.

Comment: @RiggsFolly  Thank you for the help I already asked for an admin mysql key to the system admin to turn the log on. He just told me it makes the server performance 15% worse so it should be a temporal change...

Comment: It would be a good idea to set yourself up a development environment so you have contorl over all this type of stuff while developing. Developing on a hosted server is never a good idea

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is a development server apart from production but I don't know why the logs were disabled in a _development server_ ... (logic) Now is restarting I will tell you in a while how this went and if I found the error I'll answer my self.

Comment: @RiggsFolly You were completly right, the binded parameters are wrong, $lat and $long are never binded, instead I binded $latitude and $longitude, which are obviously NULL, therefor the query had no results but the script execution didn't have any errors... It ended up being a dumb thing. Thanks so much for the monitoring, feel free to answer the post.

Comment: [So this comment way early on in the conversation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497020/prepared-statement-not-working-while-sql-query-gets-results?noredirect=1#comment60602226_36497020) should have been heeded

Comment: @RiggsFolly It wasn't quite a data type but a complete variable mismatch, but yes as I admited you were right on track and you helped me to solve that :) The thing that complete confused me was the lack of errors or any kind of feedback, just an empty response. I have to think about a function to check those kind of issues...